# Validate XML without root schema

Tags: java, xml

Is there an easy way to validate an XML file without a schema in the root node but which has a schema in on of the child tags?  Would I just have to parse through the XML file, build a new Document from a child node and perform a validation on that "sub" document?

...
   
   
...

Comment: What do you mean by 'schema in the root node'? You don't need any schema in the document you are validating to validate it.

Comment: I guess he wants to validate part of xml document with schema. for example exclude root but validate all its child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doesn't need to specify the schema's in the instance document for you to validate it. Read the [Declaring the Schemas in the Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPDOM8.html) section of the documentation.